# Reading stack pointer value in ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I am trying to store value of SP register to a variable in C, here is my code:

```
int address = 0;
asm volatile ("STR sp, [%0]\n\t"
     : "=r" ( address)
     );
```

but after executing this code, os print "Segmentation fault" message in screen and terminate the programme. can any one give me a advise to solve the problem?

Comment: Since you specified register destination, don't use `STR` ... just `MOV %0, sp`

Comment: Often you can just take the address of a local var to get an address that's somewhere in the stack frame of the current function.  Or use `__builtin_frame_address(0)` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html.  But yes, with inline asm you definitely just want `mov` to `%0`.  Generally use `intptr_t address`, not just `int`, to hold a pointer, although yes on 32-bit ARM `int` can hold pointers.

Comment: For inline asm even better version: `register void* address __asm__("sp"); __asm__ __volatile__("" : "=r" (address));`

Comment: @Jester: You'd think that would be good, but ARM gcc actually destroys SP by doing `mov sp, r3` first. https://godbolt.org/z/-DEbAD.  I was playing around with `"+r"(sp)` as a possible answer to [Print out value of stack pointer](//stackoverflow.com/q/20059673) - with `"+r"` instead of `"=r"`, we get mov r3,sp / mov sp,r3 / mov r0,sp so it's still terrible on ARM.  But it works nicely for x86, where it lets GCC store RSP directly to a memory destination without a reg-reg `mov` if it wants to.

Comment: @PeterCordes looks like a regression. The gcc 4.3.3 I have works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't even touch the stack pointer in inline assembly. It's a taboo!!!

You aren't supposed to do that to start with. Just leave it to the compiler.

If you aren't altering the stack pointer or writing anything onto the stack, it might work, you just used the wrong instruction.

What you want to do: copy the stack pointer to a 32bit register.

What you did: store the stack pointer itself to the address 0. ==> segmentation fault.

Replace `STR sp, [%0]\n\t` with `mov %0, sp\n\t`

Comment: The `address = 0` initializer could have been optimized away, leaving whatever garbage was in a register.  It's an `"=r"` output-only constraint, not `"+r"`, so any earlier assignments to `address` are dead at that point.  So the store address could easily have been some garbage, not 0.